# Could not find function or function reference 'request.security' error in Code

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I created a simple script to draw a Fibonacci retracement from the opening price of a current daily candle to the opening price of the previous daily candle. Script will not run.....
Error message is **Could not find function or function reference request security

Added existing script below, don't understand why it won't work or how to fix error.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...Thanks in advance.

```
//@version=4
study("Fibonacci Retracement from Previous Daily Candle", overlay=true)

// Define previous daily opening price
prevOpen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[1])

// Define current daily opening price
curOpen = open

// Fibonacci levels calculation
fibLevel0 = prevOpen
fibLevel1 = prevOpen + (curOpen - prevOpen) * 0.236
fibLevel2 = prevOpen + (curOpen - prevOpen) * 0.382
fibLevel3 = prevOpen + (curOpen - prevOpen) * 0.618
fibLevel4 = prevOpen + (curOpen - prevOpen) * 1

// Plotting Fibonacci retracement levels
plot(fibLevel0, "0%", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(fibLevel1, "23.6%", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(fibLevel2, "38.2%", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(fibLevel3, "61.8%", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(fibLevel4, "100%", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

// Fill area between Fibonacci levels
fill(fibLevel0, fibLevel1, color=color.red, transp=85)
fill(fibLevel1, fibLevel2, color=color.yellow, transp=85)
fill(fibLevel2, fibLevel3, color=color.green, transp=85)
fill(fibLevel3, fibLevel4, color=color.blue, transp=85)
```

Comment: Do you use chatGPT to generate code?
security() function is renamed to request.security only in pine v5, but your code using pine v4